# Returning NULL from query for datatables

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I'm wondering what would be best to do. Right now I have running a query to see if I have any results returned and if none are returned I return NULL.

On my controller I send that resultset whether it be an object or NULL to my table and it echos the rows on the view page.

For my tables I am using the jquery datatables plugin. I'm trying to figure out how I can have it handle the data when the sent value is NULL that way it doesn't show me an error when it hits my foreach loop.

Controller:

```
$news_articles = $this->news_model->get_news_articles();
$this->data['news_articles'] = $news_articles;
```

Model:

```
/**
 * Get news articles
 *
 * @return  object
 */
function get_news_articles()
{   
    $query = $this->db->get($this->news_articles_table);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();
    return NULL;
}
```

View:

```
$tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table class="table" id="newsarticles-table">' );
$data = array('name' => 'newsarticles', 'class' => 'selectall');
$this->table->set_heading(form_checkbox($data), 'ID', 'Date', 'Title');            
$this->table->set_template($tmpl);             
foreach ($news_articles as $row)
{
    $checkbox_data = array(
        'name'        => 'newsarticles',
        'id'          => $row->id
    );
    $this->table->add_row(form_checkbox($checkbox_data), $row->id, $row->date_posted, $row->article_title);
}
echo $this->table->generate();
```

Comment: In similar situations, I've taken to returning empty collections.  Saves all the null checking.

Comment: Could you show me an example from my code.

Comment: In get_news_articles, instead of return NULL, try return new array().  That will return an empty array, the foreach loop will not iterate, and then ... well, you're at the mercy of data tables at that point.  I don't know what it'll do with no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return an empty array from the model, if there are not results. That way your foreach won't break. It just won't loop over anything.

Answer (score 2):

I typically respond using JSON and then add a "success" type boolean and then check that value before trying to process any data.  It also allows for an easy way to place an error message in the response if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just another idea

**Model**

```
function get_news_articles()
{   
    $query = $this->db->get($this->news_articles_table);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();
    return FALSE;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$news_articles = $this->news_model->get_news_articles();
if(!$news_articles) $this->data['success'] = FALSE;
else
{
    $this->data['news_articles'] = $news_articles;
    $this->data['success'] = TRUE;
}
```

**In the view**

```
if($success)
{
    foreach ($news_articles as $row)
    {
        //....
    }
}
else echo "No results found !";
```